# Why friendly url with ASP.NET MVC5 Routing attributes doesn't work everytime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to know why a friendly URL is generated from one action and not on the other.

Let's me show you!

```
    [RoutePrefix("fr-ca/guest")]
    public class GuestController : BaseController
    {        
        [Route("users/{id:int}/{ids:int}")]
        public ActionResult Index(int id, int ids)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Route("register/{id:int}/{ids:int}")]
        public ActionResult Register(int id, int ids)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

To get the friendly URL results, I use Razor like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("some text", "Index", "Guest", new { id = 1, ids = 1 }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("some other text", "Register", "Guest", new { id = 1, ids = 1 }, null)
```

And in the route config file I added this line: `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

So the first on work properly, I get the **http:.../fr-ca/guest/users/1/1**
But the second one doesn't work! I get **http:.../fr-ca/guest/register?id=1&ids=1**

Anyone can help?

Thank you!!

David

Comment: How do you have defined RouteConfig's RegisterConfig method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Html.ActionLink` you can use `Html.RouteLink`. This helper has an overload that takes the name of a route to be used. You must add a name to your route though:

In your controller:

```
[Route("register/{id:int}/{ids:int}", Name="GuestRegister")]
public ActionResult Register(int id, int ids)
{
    return View();        
}
```

In your view:

```
@Html.RouteLink("some other text", "GuestRegister", new { id = 1, ids = 1 }, null)
```

This results in:

```
http://.../fr-ca/guest/register/1/1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not have any other route definition which is conflicting with this,

`@Html.ActionLink("some other text", "Register", "Guest", new { id = 1, ids = 1 }, null)`  will generate anchor tag with href value as `http://yoursitename/fr-ca/guest/register/1/1` , not `http:.../fr-ca/guest/register?id=1&ids=1`

Since you have specified the pattern as `register/{id:int}/{ids:int}` It should work fine for `register/1/1` url, but not for `/register?id=1&ids=2` . That is the expected behavior.

Comment: Your answer point me in the right direction. It's working if I change the name of Register. The reason is I have Account/Register and Guest/Register. I thought it could works if I had two different friendly URL like : fr-ca/account/register and fr-ca/guest/register. Do you know if I can make it working by adding something to the route attribute?